# Basic statistics about any Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, statistics

Is there any place with statisics about each Stack Exchange site? For example, I would like to know when the chemistry site was started and how many questions were asked and answered every year.

Maybe there is a place like **http://stats.chemistry.stackexchange.com/** or something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to using Area 51, there are other tools available as well. The [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) is a pretty neat tool, and you can find many working queries that other users have generously wrote. You should be able to find things there.

The downside to Area 51 is that they only track stats for a limited time period (in beta phases), and they don't offer flexibility with the data. They only track average question traffic, % answered, # of users, and the visits per day, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 6):

You can find some of those stats in [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/). For **sites still in beta**, check the ["beta tab"](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta) for all proposals. Click on the link for the site in question to see basic stats. You can find stats about graduated sites on the "launched" tab, but only stats from when they graduated. Some of these include when they entered private beta.

For stats about **graduated sites** - and all sites, in fact - go to the [Stack Exchange sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and choose how you want to filter the list of sites. Go to the section for the site you want for more information.

Comment: The area 51 stats stop after beta.

Comment: @Tim I'm aware; that's why I indicated that ("For sites in still in beta" and "from when they graduated") and gave a link to the general stats page.